# Read message from a file in python and publish it via sns topic

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sns

I have a requirement to read output from txt file and this is result from a python script execution. This .txt file output/content needs to be published via sns topic . Can someone help me on this please?

```
import boto3
sns = boto3.client('sns')
# Publish a simple message to the specified SNS topic
response = sns.publish(
TopicArn='arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxx',   
Message='Message',

)
# Print out the response
 print(response)
```

Comment: You want to know how to publish via SNS topic ?

Comment: @KnowledgeGainer I wanna know how to read the .txt file in the message

Comment: Can you add your input and expected output in the question for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the .txt like this

```
with open("/path/to/txt/file.txt", "r") as txt_file:
    output = txt_file.read() # might need .readlines() or .read().splitlines(). Whatever works for you
    Message = output
```

Comment: Thanks it worked.  

Do you know how to add a custom subject to the sns publish . Currently it says " Aws notification message "

Comment: I've never used boto3 so you'll have to read the documentation.
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html

Comment: Add Subject='my custom subject here' to the publish method